# Similar Matrices of order 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Two matrices $A,B$ from this domain are similar if $ A = CBC^{-1}$ for some $ C \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$. How would I go about finding representatives for the similarity classes of matrices $A$ of order 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a matrix has order $6$, then it satisfies the polynomial $$t^6-1 = (t^3-1)(t^3+1) = (t-1)(t+1)(t^2+t+1)(t^2-t+1).$$ Hence the minimal polynomial, which must be of degree at most $2$, is either $t-1$, $t+1$, $t^2-1$, $t^2+t+1$, or $t^2-t+1$. It cannot be $t-1$,  $t+1$, or $t^2-1$ (that would mean the matrix has order $1$ or $2$).

*Added.* And as pointed out by [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) and [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel) (and overlooked by me), if the minimal polynomial is $t^2+t+1$, then the minimal polynomial divides $t^3-1$, so the matrix will have order $3$.

So you are looking for matrices with minimal polynomial $t^2-t+1$; this is also their characteristic polynomial.

So you just need to figure out the rational canonical form of matrices with characteristic polynomial $t^2-t+1$.

Comment: If it was $t^2+t+1$, the matrix would have order $3$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Oops, quite so. Silly me.

Comment: @Jyrki: Quite so, silly me.